# Align element to the second column

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I have the following layout:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#a {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
#b {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 150px;
}
#c {
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 100px;
}

/* Less relevant styles */
#a, #b, #c {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#a {
  background-color: #FFC300;
}
#b {
  background-color: #FF5733;
}
#c {
  background-color: #C70039;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="b">B</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

How can I change the A element so that instead of taking up all the horizontal space, it's aligned to the C element? Basically I want to achieve something like that:

[image: The desired result]

Note that I don't want to set something like `margin-left: 33%` on the A element, because I don't know if the B element will always take up one third of the horizontal space. I want the A element to remain aligned to C even if the width of B or C changes.

If possible, I want to achieve this using flexbox, but I'm open to workarounds.

Comment: This is possible if you can change the structure of the html and add a div encompassing `A` and `C` and another div encompassing `B`. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @Yathi I would like to avoid adding divs with no semantic meaning, unless there's no other way.

Comment: What would you like to happen if B width changes to 100%?

Comment: @chrona B will never have a width of 100%.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of layout is standard for a table element (especially because of the variable width of each column). Something to consider, if possible.

Basically, you need to force "A" and "C" into the same column so they can track each other's width.

One method would be to force "B" to consume all space in the first column. This can be done by nesting "B" in a container with 100% height, then aligning "B" to the bottom half.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 200px;
}

nested-container {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
#b {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #FF5733;
}
#a {
  background-color: #FFC300;
}
#c {
  background-color: #C70039;
}

#a, #b, #c
{
  height: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <nested-container>
    <div id="b">B</div>
  </nested-container>
  <div id="a">A</div>
  <div id="c">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of that solution, but I would like to avoid adding divs with no semantic meaning.

Comment: @Gothdo, I simplified my solution. No need for a duplicate item, but it still uses an extra container.

Comment: Similarly as with Paulie_D's solution, it doesn't work when B's height is greater than C's height. I want the top of B to be in the same line as the top of C.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping nested flexboxes and `justify-content:flex-end` is one option.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}
[class^="wrap"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
/* Less relevant styles */

#a,
#b,
#c {
  height: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#a {
  background-color: #FFC300;
}
#b {
  background-color: #FF5733;
}
#c {
  background-color: #C70039;
}
.wrap-left {
  flex: 1;
}
.wrap-right {
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrap-left">
    <div id="b">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap-right">
    <div id="a">A</div>
    <div id="c">C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if B's height is greater than C's. I want the top of B to be in the same line as the top of C.

Comment: Unfortunately, then what you are after cannot really be acheive with flexbox I suspect. Especially since you cannot align elements that do not share a parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can group your boxes this way:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="first-col">
        <div id="empty"></div>
        <div id="b">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-col">
        <div id="a">A</div>
        <div id="c">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and style their width togehter by column, but their color and content by id